# Function Suddenly Stopped Working

Tags: functions

I have a function which allows users to choose between pagination and next/previous links.  In fact, I was provided the function on this site.  I tested it today and it suddenly isn't working.  I can't figure out the cause of this sudden interruption.

It seems that the code will work if I choose the option I want, switch themes, save, then switch back!  Absolutely no idea what is going on.

In functions.php:

```
// Pagination
function my_theme_navigation() 
{ 
    global $shortname;

    if( get_option( $shortname . '_next_prev_or_paginate' ) == 'Next' ) : 
        // the block for next-prev navigation
        echo '<div class="left">';
        next_posts_link('Older');
        echo '</div>';
        echo '<div class="right">';
        previous_posts_link ('Newer');
        echo '</div>';
    else : 
        // the block for pagination
        global $wp_query;
        $big = 999999999; // need an unlikely integer
        echo paginate_links(
            array(
                'base' => str_replace( $big, '%#%', get_pagenum_link( $big ) ),
                'format' => '?paged=%#%',
        'end_size'     => 1,
        'mid_size'     => 2,
                'current' => max( 1, get_query_var('paged') ), 
                'total' => $wp_query->max_num_pages
            )
        ); 
    endif; 
}
```

In my options panel:

```
array( "name" => "Paginate or next/previous links?", 
    "desc" => "Choose your option", 
    "id" => $shortname."_next_prev_or_paginate", 
    "type" => "select", 
    "options" => array("Next/Previous Links", "Pagination"), 
    "std" => "Next"),
```

In index.php:

```
<?php my_theme_navigation(); ?>
```

Comment: Do you have [debugging information](http://codex.wordpress.org/Debugging_in_WordPress) that you could add?

Comment: Which information would you like?

Comment: Anything you have. Follow the link. If you enable debugging, load that page and something pops up it might be relevant. Also, server logs if relevant. Are you sure you didn't do something just before this happened?

Comment: I am sure.  But I'm not 100% sure how to enable debugging.

Comment: [debugging information](http://codex.wordpress.org/Debugging_in_WordPress)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is your problem:

```
"options" => array("Next/Previous Links", "Pagination"), 
"std" => "Next"
```

Your valid options don't match your default.

Change this:

```
"std" => "Next"
```

...to this:

```
"std" => "Next/Previous Links"
```

Then, in your function call, change this:

```
if( get_option( $shortname . '_next_prev_or_paginate' ) == 'Next' )
```

...to this:

```
if( get_option( $shortname . '_next_prev_or_paginate' ) == 'Next/Previous Links' )
```